# how to remove error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++

please help me remove this error i made these two structures and when i try to use the cin it shows this error how can i remove this error and please also tell me how to take a string in input using cin.getline and gets().

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Date //Date structure
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
struct Employee   //employee structure
{
    int Id;
    char Name[40];
    int Date;
    char Gender;
    char Des[40];
};
void Setter(Employee E)   //function for setting value in Employees 
{
    cout<<"Enter Id:";
    cin>>Employee.Id;
    cout<<"Enter Name:";
    cin>>Employee.Name;
    cout<<"Enter Gender:";
    cin>>Employee.Gender;
    cout<<"Enter Designation:";
    cin>>Employee.Des;
    cout<<"Enter Date of joining(DD/MM/YYYY):";
    cin>>Employee.Date.day>>Employee.Date.month>>Employee.Date.year;
}
int main() //main
{
    Employee el;
    Setter(el);   //calling function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Extremely similar: [Error : expected primary-expression before '.' token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958577/error-expected-primary-expression-before-token?rq=1)

Comment: Change `Employee` to `E`, that simple.

Comment: Capitalizing both your class names and your properties is going to drive other people up the wall. It's usually a lot more conventional to have the properties and variables start lower-case, like in your Date example.  Additionally, 40 characters for a name is crazy short. Is there any reason to not use `std::string` here? That's way better than copying C-style string buffers around.

Answer (score 1):

`Employee` is a type name and itself doesn't have members to read data in.
Use the variable to access members.

Additionally, you may want to use a reference to modify caller's local variable.
Add `&` after the type name to use reference.

```
void Setter(Employee& E)   //function for setting value in Employees 
{
    cout<<"Enter Id:";
    cin>>E.Id;
    cout<<"Enter Name:";
    cin>>E.Name;
    cout<<"Enter Gender:";
    cin>>E.Gender;
    cout<<"Enter Designation:";
    cin>>E.Des;
    cout<<"Enter Date of joining(DD/MM/YYYY):";
    //cin>>E.Date.day>>E.Date.month>>E.Date.year;
}
```

Note that the comment-outed line

```
cin>>E.Date.day>>E.Date.month>>E.Date.year;
```

is wrong because the type of `E.Date` is `int` and it won't have members. You will have to alter the strucure's declaration to let the structure hold a date (or three additional integers).

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: Note `E.Date.day` still won't work.

Comment: How can i make it work then

Comment: @Hamid I guess you should add a member having type `Date` and read the data into it.

Comment: Similar problem with `Name`, unless OP wants only the first or last name.